# What do quotes mean in iOS8 predictive text?

Tags: keyboard, ios

In the new iOS8 predictive text feature, three suggested words appear above the traditional keyboard.
The left hand word is frequently, but not always, surrounded by quotes.

What do the quotes mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes signify "learn" or "use this word" whether or not it's a recognisable word to the predictive system.

Without quotes it is part of the next word prediction; as soon as you start typing a new word the system then focusses on that current word, offering 2 suggestions & an "accept what I just wrote" option.